# Handling org.xml.sax.SAXParseException while reading and writing an XML file using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, java-7

I'm creating an XML file using JAXB as follows.

```
public final class Main
{
    private File file;
    private transient JAXBContext jaxb;
    List<Fruit>fruits;

    private void test()
    {
        try {
            jaxb=JAXBContext.newInstance(Fruits.class);
            file=new File(System.getenv("UPLOAD_LOCATION")+"\\xml_files\\fruits.xml");

            Marshaller marshaller = jaxb.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.FALSE);

            if(!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
                marshaller.marshal(new Fruits(new ArrayList<Fruit>()), file);
            }
            else {
                fruits=((Fruits) jaxb.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(file)).getList();
            }

            for(Fruit fruit:fruits) {
                System.out.println(fruit.getId()+" : "+fruit.getName()+" : "+fruit.getPrice());
            }

        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }/*catch (SAXParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }*/
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Main().test();
    }
}
```

The code that adds objects is excluded. It however generates an XML file something like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<fruits>
    <fruit id="1">
        <name>Mango</name>
        <price>100</price>
    </fruit>
    <fruit id="2">
        <name>Banana</name>
        <price>50</price>
    </fruit>
    <fruit id="3">
        <name>Pineapple</name>
        <price>80</price>
    </fruit>
</fruits>
```

If this XML file is invalidated for certain reasons, like it may be modified externally.

If this file contains some mulformed XML format then, it throws `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException`. If this exception is thrown then, I want to recreate this file. Otherwise, the exception will be thrown continually unless the XML contents is manually modified and restructured. For this to be so, this exception should be caught.

The compiler refuses to catch this exception. If an additional `catch` block for this exception is attempted as shown in the code snipped then, it complains,

> exception `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException` is never thrown in body of
>   corresponding `try` statement

How to handle this exception so that the file can be recreated (deleting the old one) in case, this exception is thrown?

<sub>I'm not showing the classes (`Fruit` and `Fruits`) that create XML elements, since they are not quite related to this question.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SAXParseException` is a checked exception and is not declared on the method `unmarshal()`, so it's normal that you cannot catch it.

There is another exception that you could catch, which is `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException`. this exception extends `javax.xml.bind.JAXBException` so you have to put your `catch` block before `JAXBException`.

In the documentation of the method `unmarshal()` it says that `UnmarshalException` is thrown, if a validation error occurs or the `Unmarshaller` is unable to perform the XML to Java binding.

Note: I verified in the implementation of the `Unmarshaller` and when an
`org.xml.sax.SAXException` occurs, it is wrapped in a `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException`.